# MSAccess Conn in C# (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I am using VS 2010 and C#. I want to connect to an MDB in C#. 'till now what I have done is as follows:

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Databases\\"+DBname+".mdb";

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;

try
{
    myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);

    OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(Query, myAccessConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

    myAccessConn.Open();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Table");
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    myAccessConn.Close();
}
```

The database returns the valid DataSet ... thats not the problem for Access 2000 Database

However when I change the connection string to

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Databases\\"+DBname+".mdb";
```

for MSAccess2007 the database path is not found and an exception is generated although it exist. Am I missing any references?

Comment: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0` are you sure? Do you mean `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`? And what is the exception message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Access data file extension from `.mdb` to `.accdb`:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Databases\\"+DBname+".accdb";
```

See [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007) for reference.